# use adf pipeline parameters as source to sink columns while mapping

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have an ADF pipeline with copy activity, I'm copying data from blob storage CSV file to SQL database, this is working as expected. I need to map Name of the CSV file (this coming from pipeline parameters) and save it in the destination table. I'm wondering if there is a way to map parameters to destination columns.

Answer (score 1):

Column name can't directly use parameters. But you can use parameter for the whole structure property in dataset and columnMappings property in copy activity. 
This might be a little tedious as you will need to write the whole structure array and columnMappings on your own and pass them as parameters into pipeline.

Comment: thank you for the input. We are using U-SQL for other transformations in same pipeline. we were able to map file name from U-SQL activity.

Answer (score 0):

In DF v2 in Copy Data activity, it is possible to add a new column to the source with value $$FILEPATH, and then each record will have a name of the input file.

Azure DF v2, CopyData activity -> Source
[image: CopyData activity -> Source]