# Data Factory - append fields to JSON sink

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am using the copy activity to copy/transform a JSON source dataset into JSON sink dataset. Need to append a few audit fields to the output - such as transform date using @utcnow expression function.

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: For clarity, you only need to modify the JSON by adding the audit fields.  You're don't need to append the JSON content to an existing JSON instance.  Right?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the databricks activity handles this functionality pretty well.

```
df_new = df.select("table.field1","table.field2","table.field3").withColumn("TransferDate", current_timestamp())
```