# Azure Data Factory activity copy get multiple table name from foreach activity

Tags: azure, foreach, azure-data-factory

with Data Factory V2 I'm trying to implement a stream of data copy from one Azure SQL database to another.
I have to merge multiple tables into one target table.

To do this I created a lookup activity that creates the name of the three tables to be copied. The output `JSON` file is passed to a foreach activity that should copy the data of each table into the destination table, but the pipeline execution is not successful.

I report the code of my pipeline below:

```
{
"name": "FLD_Item_base",
"properties": {
    "activities": [
        {
            "name": "myLookup",
            "type": "Lookup",
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "activity": "myStoredProcedure",
                    "dependencyConditions": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "policy": {
                "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                "retry": 0,
                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                "secureOutput": false,
                "secureInput": false
            },
            "typeProperties": {
                "source": {
                    "type": "SqlSource",
                    "sqlReaderQuery": "SELECT tsy_company_desc, tsy_tabella_desc, tsy_company_id, \ncase when tsy_company_desc = 'all' \nthen '['+ tsy_tabella_desc + ']' else '['+tsy_company_desc + '$' + tsy_tabella_desc + ']'  end as nome_tabella_completo \nfrom dbo.TSY_FLUSSI_LOAD_DWH \nwhere tsy_flusso_desc = 'item_base' \nand tsy_tabella_desc='Item' \n"
                },
                "dataset": {
                    "referenceName": "TLD_Item",
                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                },
                "firstRowOnly": false
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "myStoredProcedure",
            "type": "SqlServerStoredProcedure",
            "policy": {
                "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                "retry": 0,
                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                "secureOutput": false,
                "secureInput": false
            },
            "typeProperties": {
                "storedProcedureName": "[dbo].[myStoredProcedure]"
            },
            "linkedServiceName": {
                "referenceName": "Sink",
                "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "IterateSQLTables",
            "type": "ForEach",
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "activity": "myLookup",
                    "dependencyConditions": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "typeProperties": {
                "items": {
                    "value": "@activity('myLookup').output",
                    "type": "Expression"
                },
                "activities": [
                    {
                        "name": "FullCopyActivity",
                        "type": "Copy",
                        "policy": {
                            "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                            "retry": 0,
                            "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                            "secureOutput": false,
                            "secureInput": false
                        },
                        "typeProperties": {
                            "source": {
                                "type": "SqlSource",
                                "sqlReaderQuery": {
                                    "value": "SELECT * FROM @{item().value.name_tab}",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            },
                            "sink": {
                                "type": "SqlSink",
                                "writeBatchSize": 10000
                            },
                            "enableStaging": false,
                            "dataIntegrationUnits": 0
                        },
                        "inputs": [
                            {
                                "referenceName": "Source",
                                "type": "DatasetReference"
                            }
                        ],
                        "outputs": [
                            {
                                "referenceName": "TLD_Item",
                                "type": "DatasetReference"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
```

Pipeline execution returns the following error:

```
{
"errorCode": "400",
"message": "Activity failed because an inner activity failed",
"failureType": "UserError",
"target": "IterateSQLTables"
}
```

Does anyone know how to solve the problem? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try `@activity('myLookup').output.value` instead of `@activity('myLookup').output` in the `items` of activity `IterateSQLTables`.

You can find document for lookup activity [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-lookup-activity#use-the-lookup-activity-result-in-a-subsequent-activity)

Comment: Sorry, do you also know how to enter the pipeline run time in a sink table column, not mapped?

Comment: To append a column, you might reference this link.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51853329/add-file-name-as-column-in-data-factory-pipeline-destination/51858408#51858408

Comment: @Sidney Wang maybe you also know how to solve this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52612382/azure-data-factory-select-property-status-succeeded-from-previous-activity