# Azure Data Factory select property "status": "Succeeded" from previous activity

Tags: azure, if-statement, azure-data-factory

with Data Factory V2 I'm trying to implement a stream of data copy from one Azure SQL database to another.

I would like to perform a conditional activity `If Condition` depends on the success of the previous activities execute by the pipeline, but in the expression to be included in the activity of `If Condition` I can not select the output property `"status": "Succeeded"`.

Before the activity of `If Condition` I have two data copy activities.

I added an `If Condition` activity to my flow because the tasks to perform after copying the data depend on the success of **all** the copy activities.

i.e.

if all copy activities are performed correctly then the true condition will be executed. If only one copy activity is successful and the other fails then the false condition is executed

The output of each copy activities is as follows:

```
Output
{
    "dataRead": 213156,
    "dataWritten": 213156,
    "rowsRead": 3554,
    "rowsCopied": 3554,
    "copyDuration": 4,
    "throughput": 52.04,
    "errors": [],
    "effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "DefaultIntegrationRuntime (West Europe)",
    "usedDataIntegrationUnits": 4,
    "usedParallelCopies": 1,
    "executionDetails": [
        {
            "source": {
                "type": "AzureSqlDatabase"
            },
            "sink": {
                "type": "AzureSqlDatabase"
            },
            "status": "Succeeded",
            "start": "2018-10-02T13:42:37.7396813Z",
            "duration": 4,
            "usedDataIntegrationUnits": 4,
            "usedParallelCopies": 1,
            "detailedDurations": {
                "queuingDuration": 3,
                "preCopyScriptDuration": 0,
                "timeToFirstByte": 0,
                "transferDuration": 1
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And I structured my expression for `If Condition` activity like that:

```
@and(equals(activity('Copy_Activity1').output.executionDetails[3],'Succeeded'), equals(activity('Copy_Activity2').output.executionDetails[3],'Succeeded'))
```

But he gives me the following error:

```
"error": {
    "code": "InvalidTemplate",
    "message": "Unable to process template language expressions in action 'If Condition1' inputs at line '1' and column '1294': 'The template language expression 'and(equals(activity('Copy_Item_Budget_Name').output.executionDetails[3],'Succeeded'), equals(activity('Copy_Item_Budget_Entry').output.executionDetails[3],'Succeeded'))' cannot be evaluated because array index '3' is outside bounds (0, 0) of array. Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions for usage details.'."
}
```

But even with the guide I can not solve the problem.

Does anyone know how to solve the problem? Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the output data, `executionDetails` is an array with only one item which contains an object. So the expression should be: `activity('Copy_Activity1').output.executionDetails[0].status`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I tried it but I get this error now: 
`"error": { "code": "InvalidTemplate", "message": "Unable to process template language expressions in action 'If Condition1' inputs at line '1' and column '1294': 'The template language expression 'and(equals(activity('Copy_Activity1').output.executionDetails[0].status,'Succeeded'),equals(activity('Copy_Activity2').executionDetails[0].status, 'Succeeded'))' cannot be evaluated because property '0' cannot be selected. Object properties can only be selected by names. Please see (...)'." }`  why??

Comment: Is `executionDetails`  an array or object?

Comment: Or can you try `activity('Copy_Activity2').executionDetails[0]['status']`

Comment: `executionDetails` is an array

Comment: Could you please try `first(activity('Copy_Activity2').executionDetails).status` or `first(activity('Copy_Activity2').executionDetails)['status']` ?

Comment: I tried both solutions above, but execution returns this error `"error": {
        "code": "InvalidTemplate",
        "message": "Unable to process template language expressions in action 'If Condition1' inputs at line '1' and column '1294': 'The template language function 'first' expects its parameter be an array or a string. The provided value is of type 'Object'. Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions#first for usage details.'."
    }` does this mean that `executionDetails` is an object and not an array?

Comment: That's wierd. I tried `@and(equals(activity('Copy Data1').output.executionDetails[0].status, 'Succeeded'), equals(activity('Copy Data2').output.executionDetails[0].status, 'Succeeded'))` It works well. Could you replace the activity name with the expression and try again?

Comment: Oh I see. from the error message in your first comment, `activity('Copy_Activity2').executionDetails[0].status`, you lost `.output` here. Please change to `activity('Copy_Activity2').output.executionDetails[0].status`

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to **run some activities after ALL the copy activities completed successfully**, Johns-305's answer is actually correct.

Here's the example with more detailed information. Copy activities are `activity 1` and `activity 2`, other activities to run after them are `activity 3` and `activity 4`, no dependency between `activity 3` and `activity 4`. The activities should be linked as below picture. Please be aware that, the `activity 3` and `activity 4` will not be run twice, they will be run only after **both** of `activity 1` and `activity 2` are succeeded.
[image: Activity graph of the example]

Comment: Ok I understand this, but my problem is the following: after the copy activities I must overwrite a single row in a sql table with the outcome of both copy activity with: 'ok' if both are completed, 'ko' if one or both are not successful. If I follow the diagram above, adding the connector for the failure output and connecting both connectors of all copy activities to the following activities, if a copy activity is successful and the other is not, how will my row in the sql table be updated?

Comment: So the requirement is actually not to `run some activities after ALL the copy activities completed successfully`, but to `run some activities after ALL the copy activities completed, no matter succeeded or failed, and make the activities run differently according the result of the copy activities`. Bo Xiao's answer should be the correct one in this case.

Answer (score -2):

For clarity, that's not how flow control works in ADF.

You don't need to query the result of the previous shape, instead, you change the Activity Connector to branch based on the outcome.

After connecting two Activities, right click on the line/arrow.  Then you can choose to run the next Activity on any of Success, Failure, Completion or Skip.

You can link any number of Activities before and after it.

Comment: yes I know that there are various types of connectors based on the output of the previous activity, but my problem is another and maybe I was not clear in the question. The activities contained in the if true condition should only be performed if ALL of the previous copy activities have been performed correctly. If only one of the copy activities fails (and all the others are done correctly) then the false activity must be performed. How can I manage this flow?