# Azure data factory logical function expression invalid

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I've got an ADF pipeline which is supposed to ETL job. I've added IF CONDITION which should evaluate the last result(of **Copy Data** Activity) obtained(If the output is **Succeeded** then true activity should be executed.). While writing the expression
I'm following the syntax but its failing in debugging.
What am I missing in the expression?

Further, I'll be evaluating output from **Wait** activity also since the output of Wait activity is *{}* how to evaluate the activity in the same way I'm evaluating **Copy Data** Activity?

[image: Expression]

[image: Debug Output]

[image: Output of FS1 to Blob]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having almost the same issue.
Please refer to the below post.

[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52612382/azure-data-factory-select-property-status-succeeded-from-previous-activity)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you are still having a problem with this, but it appears that you have one too many parentheses.

```
@equals(activity('FS1 to Blob').output.status), 'Success')
                                             ^
```

So it would appear that `equals()` only has the activity output as input.
Get rid of that and try it then!