# Is there a way to add a column in the copy activity?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have to call a webservice with multiple times with a diferent parameter value.

therefore i created a foreach task containing a copy activity.

Now i want to save the output of this call along with the parameter value.

Cann i somehow add a new additional field in the copy activity mapping to my parameter value? (@item().value)

Answer (score 0):

what is your copy source type? You might use a query to include the item().value

You could also reference this post.
[Add file name as column in data factory pipeline destination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51853329/add-file-name-as-column-in-data-factory-pipeline-destination/51858408#51858408)

Comment: Hi its a httpfile, unfortunatly i cannot add this expression.