# Azure data factory pipeline - copy blob and store filename in a DocumentDB or in Azure SQL

Tags: azure-data-factory

I set up 2 blob storage folders called "input" and "output". My pipeline gets triggered when a new file arrives in "input" and copies that file to the "output" folder. Furthermore I do have a Get Metadata activity where I receive the copied filename(s).

Now I would like to store the filename(s) of the copied data into a DocumentDB.
I tried to use the ForEach activity with it, but here I am stuck.

Basically I tried to use parts from this answer: [Add file name as column in data factory pipeline destination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51853329/add-file-name-as-column-in-data-factory-pipeline-destination/51858408#51858408)

But I don't know what to assign as Source in the CopyData activity since my source are the filenames from the ForEach activity - or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your requirements, I suggest you using [Blob Trigger Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-storage-blob-triggered-function) to combine with your current Azure data factory business.

Step 1: still use event trigger in adf to transfer between input and output.

Step 2: assign Blob Trigger Azure Functions to output folder.

Step 3: the function will be triggered as soon as a new file created into it.Then get the file name and use Document DB SDK to store it into document db.

.net document db SDK: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-sdk-dotnet

Blob trigger bindings, please refer to here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob

Answer (score 1):

You may try use a custom activity to insert filenames into Document Db.

You can pass filenames as parameters to the custom activity, and write your own code to insert data into Document Db.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-dotnet-custom-activity