# Azure Data Factory Dynamic content parameter

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to load the data from the last runtime to lastmodifieddate from the source tables using Azure Data Factory.

this is working fine :

```
@concat(' SELECT  * FROM dbo. ',
        item().TABLE_list ,
       ' WHERE   modifieddate > DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())')"
```

when i use:

```
@concat(' SELECT  * FROM dbo.  ',
         item().TABLE_list ,
        '  WHERE   modifieddate > @{formatDateTime(
                  addhours(pipeline().TriggerTime-24)),
                  ''yyyy','-','MM','-','ddTHH',':','mm',':','ssZ''}')
```

getting error as ""errorCode": "2200",

```
"message": "Failure happened on 'Source' side. 'Type=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,Message=Must declare the scalar variable \"@\".,Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider,SqlErrorNumber=137,Class=15,ErrorCode=-2146232060,State=2,Errors=[{Class=15,Number=137,State=2,Message=Must declare the scalar variable \"@\".,},],'",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "Copy Data1"
}
```

- what mistake am I doing?
- I need to pass dynamically last run time date of pipeline after > in where condition.

Answer (score 2):

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM dbo.@{item().TABLE_LIST} 
    WHERE modifieddate > 
    @{formatDateTime(addhours(pipeline().TriggerTime, -24), 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ')}
```

You could use string interpolation expression. Concat makes things complicated.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#expressions

Comment: I have tried by removing @ at @item().tablelist but no use.

Comment: Could you share me the syntax error? Better with screenshot. You can’t remove that @ at @item.

Comment: And I guess you need add a single quote around the datetime? select * From dbo.@{item().TABLE_LIST} WHERE modifieddate > '@{formatDateTime(addhours(pipeline().TriggerTime, -24), 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ')}'

Comment: Hi Fang Liu, Can you please suggest how to sink filename of Azure data lake to database table, Used metadata and forach for the input files. I need to pass filename of the ADL path into database table.

Comment: I have gone through the link "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51853329/add-file-name-as-column-in-data-factory-pipeline-destination" posted by you

Comment: It is not supported by built-in copy. You need write your own stored-procedure or use other activities mentioned in that post.

Comment: Thanks Fang Liu, Implemented using SP. You are always special in ADF.