# Setting Default value in Data Factory Copy Activity in mappings

Tags: azure-data-factory

Just wondering how can we set a Default value in Data Factory Copy Activity in mappings.

Trying to do following

[Azure Data Factory Source Dataset value from Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53175753/azure-data-factory-source-dataset-value-from-parameter)

But if that's not possible, can I set a default value through parameter while defining mappings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve your requirement, you could define a pipeline parameter with "Object"  type and give it a default value, eg. name it as "columnMapping" and set the default value as:

```
                {
                    "type": "Object",
                    "defaultValue": {
                        "type": "TabularTranslator",
                        "columnMappings": {
                            "Prop_0": "Prop_0",
                            "Prop_1": "Prop_1",
                            "Prop_2": "Prop_2"
                        }
                    }
                }
```

then assign the parameter to the copy activity column mapping:

```
          "translator": {
                            "value": "@pipeline().parameters.columnMappings",
                            "type": "Expression"
                        }
```

Comment: Is there any way to set default value of an attribute for e.g in this case default value of "Prop_0" in data factory?