# ADF v2 Copy activity dynamic source and sink and schema mapping

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to build dynamic pipeline with explicit column mapping during the runtime.
The mapping content (tabular translator )in the copy activity can be passed as parameter , but the schema of the source or sink , I couldn't see any option to pass as parameter. can someone you guide please ?

The mapping content (tabular translator ) only gives option to do dynamic mapping on fixed source and sink schema, what I am looking for is dynamic source and sink schema and their dynamic schema mapping as well. Thanks

Comment: This seems to be duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53175753/azure-data-factory-source-dataset-value-from-parameter